# Select all records when multiple value parameter is blank

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm creating a report in SSRS and want to have a multiple value parameter but allow blank values (''), and display all records when blank.

The gist of it is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductCategories c on c.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE (c.Name IN (@Categories) OR @Categories = '')
```

Which works when blank, and works with 1 category, but errors out with 2 categories. We got around this by using a temp table, but that solution seemed sort of hacky, so I wanted to see if there was a better way to resolve this.

The temp table workaround we built was this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ProductId INT, Category NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT p.Id, c.Name
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductCategories c on c.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE c.Name IN (@Categories)

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #temp) = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT p.Id, c.Name
FROM Products p
JOIN ProductCategories c on c.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE c.Name LIKE '%'
END

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.  That said, what version of SS and how are you passing @Categories ?

Comment: Sql Server 2012. @Categories is coming from SSRS.

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) is one of many other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a split/parse function

**Example**

```
 ...
 Where @Categories = ''
       or
       C.Name in (
                    Select RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@Categories,',','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                 )
```

Here is a [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d22ee872b1852d193010776e94f259c3)  ... You'll notice Poultry was excluded, then try it when  `@Categories=''`